# how to replicate ftp directory to windows local drive

Tags: windows, batch-file, ftp, ftp-client, openvpn

FTP server contains files in one directory.

File names contain 4 character fixed prefix (PRE_ ) timestamp and some suffix
and have different extensions like

```
PRE_20140101153807.1233511.PDT-220-4362133316.ext
PRE_20140101253807.12e3511.PDT-220-5362133330-32.ext
PRE_2014010"253807.12e3511.PDT-220-78921333123.ex2
```

new files are added periodically to this directory, it may contain whole year files.

How to mirror this directory in Windows computer local hard drive ?
How to create some bat file which looks for new files added to this directory and downloads them 
if nessecary ?

Is it possible to use windows ftp.exe application for this or other solution ?

ftp folder is acced from windows via OpenVPN

Andrus.

Comment: [This lifehacker article should help.](http://lifehacker.com/304502/map-an-ftp-drive-in-windows)

Comment: It looks like this allows to accesss files from windows explorer only. How to map ftp folder so that it can used using regular windows directory list and read file API-s from application ?

Comment: `Wget.exe` has superior file handling and exclusions and has a `no clobber` switch which will keep existing files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How much data are you talking about? While it may not be very elegant, and it could be vconsidered a waste of bandwidth, it may be feasible and reliable to connect to the FTP server, turn off prompting and doing an MGET of all the files.

Alternatively, you could write a short script to connect to the server and get a list of files, then iterate through the list and see which ones are not present locally and do GETs of them.

Comment: There are 1000 files in month, total size is 3 MB. In end of year this will be 12 times more. ftp lookup needs to performed to retrite file after it appears (user creates this file from browser so she knows that new file was created), so it occurs 1000 times in month from 24 windows computers. Maybe simplest would be to use windows ftp.exe to retrieve those files, preferably only new files. Maybe ftp.exe can skip files which already exist ? Or is it possible to map ftp folder as regular windows folder. ftp access is performed via OpenVPN. Where to find sample script for this ?

Comment: Is the FTP server also Windows? And is there some reason it can't offer a CIFS/SMB share that you could work with more easily - or could you move the data just once via FTP to another server that could offer such a share? Then you could just use Windows XCOPY or ROBOCOPY to get the new files from there? Do your Windows boxes have Perl installed (e.g. ActiveState.com)?